# Delete a task in Task Scheduler using Powershell filtering on trigger type?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a particular task in `Task Scheduler` on some `Windows 10` machines.

This task has an `At system startup` trigger. Although the task is the same across systems, the task name could possibly be different on some machines.

I need to remove this task from each of the machines. For this purpose, I was looking to run a `Powershell` script on each system with the command `Unregister-ScheduledTask`.

However, I noticed that `TaskName` would probably be the primary option with this command that I could use. I was hoping to filter based on the `At system startup` trigger, just to make sure that different name doesn't cause deletion being unsuccessful on some systems.

Is there any other trick to delete tasks based on trigger type?

What I currently have, uses the task name:

```
if ($(Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "SendEmailAtStartup" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).TaskName -eq "SendEmailAtStartup") {
     Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "SendEmailAtStartup" -Confirm:$False
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to see tasks that are triggered at startup. Did you schedule something at startup? There's are several values in the `.Triggers()` field that may work for you. Based [on this list.](https://wutils.com/wmi/root/microsoft/windows/taskscheduler/msft_tasktrigger/) You likely want `MSFT_TaskLogonTrigger` or `MSFT_TaskBootTrigger` so we'll use those.

I'm going to use an if/elseif chain here to give you some options.

```
$schedtasks = Get-ScheduledTask | Select-Object -Property *

foreach ($task in $schedtasks) {

    if ($task.triggers -like 'MSFT_TaskLogonTrigger') {

        ## do this for logon trigger
        Write-Warning -Message ('I found {0}.taskname with the LOGON trigger!' -f $task)
        ## do some stuff
    }
    elseif ($task.triggers -like 'MSFT_TaskBootTrigger') {

        ## do this for boot trigger
        Write-Warning -Message ('I found {0}) with the BOOT trigger!' -f $task.taskname)
        ## do some cool stuff

    }
    else {

        ## nothing was found
        Write-Warning -Message 'This task didn't match any of our triggers.'
        ## but we will might want to log this task or tell someone

    }
}
```